# Place locations on GMap

Tags: web-services, google-maps, netbeans

If I have a list of locations defined by longitude and latitude and I want to place each of these locations on a Google Map as pins and attach a picture to each pin both as a thumbnail, and a picture that will enlarge if the user press the pin. The user can't really move the pins or place pins themselves.

Can I do this through a web service? (Like you can make in Netbeans)

And if so, how?? I can't seem to find what I am looking for at all when I search.

I can find Google Maps API references, but they don't really help at all :/

Answer (score 0):

There are several components to your question. The google-maps has a strong JS API that I would recommend using.

Several snippets to get you started:
Creating a new marker at a specified location:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.776989, -84.387000),
                map: map,
                title: '',
                draggable: true
            });
```

Customizing the marker: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Icons

Creating a new call out (infowindow):

```
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var contentString = '<div id="content">Hello,World</div>';
                    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
```

With this, you will be able to have most of the functionality that you are looking for. Your webservices can load the data into clientside JSON which can then be rendered by the Google-Maps API.